# Android app that detects changes in Intents being disabled

Tags: android

As noted in this question: [Android app to list and manage programs' intents by program](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/androidapp-to-list-and-manage-programs-intents-by-program) - there are at least 2 apps that let you manage which apps get passed which Intents.

However, having looked at both of those apps, they suffer from the same missing use case/feature:

***When you install a new version of any app on Android, the system resets all of its intents.***

So, what I am looking for, is an app that lets me counter-act this drift of re-enabled intents resulting from installing app updates (or new apps).

I'm fine with either:

1. End-to-end solution (**an app that keeps tracks of which Intents were changed/added since last run and lets me manage ONLY those**)
2. Piecemail solution (**an app that lets me export a full list of intents and their enablement status to a file** being the critical piece for this question; I can then do a "diff" command on old and new file by hand and then manage whatever the diff finds using standard Intent management apps from linked question).

Comment: Note: due to the fact that #2 makes read-only non-root apps acceptable, this question is not nearly the same as the one I linked to, in case someone is wondering about duplicates.